# Concatenating string from a list of strings

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have a list of strings and I am trying to concatenate it so its one bigger string.

```
foreach (var item in dir3)
     {
           resultDirectionHtml = string.Join(",",item.html_instructions);
     }


await EmailSent(resultDirectionHtml);
```

What happens currently is it sends only the last element of the list.
How can I make it so it concatenates all 8 or so strings and then sends it ??

Comment: Try `+=` instead of just `=`. Currently you are reassigning the entire string every loop iteration, instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+=` instead of just `=`. Currently you are reassigning the entire string every loop iteration, instead of appending to it.

So your code becomes:

```
foreach (var item in dir3)
     {
           resultDirectionHtml += string.Join(",",item.html_instructions);
     }


await EmailSent(resultDirectionHtml);
```

Comment: the only problem is, it doesn't separate the elements with the comma i mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show the output and the expected output?

Comment: I actually want them to be in new lines, and String.Join("\n", item.html_instructions); doesn't return the desired result. It returns  abcd, when I want each element in a new line. Using a comma for the separator still returns "abcd", not "a,b,c,d"

Comment: I made a workaround and it works: String.Join("\n", item.html_instructions+<br>);

Comment: Are you printing to a console or a html page? `\n` is not registered as a new line in HTML, so if you are actually printing to a html page, you could `Join` on `"<br>"` instead. If not, you could also try `resultDirectionHtml += "\n" += string.Join(",", item.html_instructions);` as demo'ed here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jcL860

Comment: <br> should also be <br />

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this:

```
using System.Text;
var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in dir3)
     {
           builder.Append(item.html_instructions);
           builder.Append("<br />");
     }

resultDirectionHtml = builder.ToString();
```

Every time you "add" to a string, it creates a new string in memory so you end up with as many strings as many items you have in that list and you keep eating away at the memory. 
it is highly recommended to not use such code in a loop.

5 or more items I would use a StringBuilder. Anything less, probably not worth it.

Comment: Good suggestion to have less memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a projection instead of the foreach loop

```
resultDirectionHtml += string.Join(",",dir3.Select(i => i.html_instructions));
```

Comment: Do you mean a dir3.SelectMany insted of  Select?

Comment: short and sweet

Comment: @gabba - No, I meant Select. I was under the impression that each `html_instructions` was a primitive value and not another enumerable (where selectmany would be appropriate). Join accepts an enumerable, for example `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(i => "Hello "+i)));` will output `Hello 0,Hello 1,Hello 2,Hello 3,Hello 4,Hello 5,Hello 6,Hello 7,Hello 8,Hello 9`

Answer (score 1):

Your code reassign the value of `resultDirectionHtml` on every iteration and hence you see only the last value. use `+=` instead of `=`

```
foreach (var item in dir3)
     {
           resultDirectionHtml += string.Join(",",item.html_instructions);
     }
```

On a different note, if you fancy using `LINQ` then you could easily write like below with the help of `Aggregate` extension.

```
string[] words = { "a", "aa", "aaa" };
var output = words.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
//The value of output will be  a, aa, aaa
```